# creating a unique id for each cell in table using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

am creating one SharePoint hosted app where am creating table from JavaScript and i there are many columns to which i need to set a unique ID am using this code

```
var itemInfo = '';
    var innerHtml = "<table border=1 class='content1'><tr><th> Room </th><th>8:00</th><th>9:00</th><th>10:00</th><th>11:00</th><th>12:00</th><th>13:00</th><th>14:00</th><th>15:00</th><th>16:00</th><th>17:00</th></tr> ";
    var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
    var count = 0;
    var count = items.get_count();

    for (var r = 0; r <= count; r++)
    {
        for (var c = 0; c <= 10; c++)
        {
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {

                var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
                if (currentListItem.get_item('Title') != null) {
                    innerHtml += "<tr><td  id=" + currentListItem.get_item('Room') + ">" + currentListItem.get_item('Room') + "</td><td id="+r+c+"></td><td id="+r+c+"></td><td id="+r+c+"></td><td id="+r+c+"></td><td id="+r+c+"></td><td id="+r+c+"></td><td id="+r+c+"></td><td id="+r+c+"></td><td id="+r+c+"></td><td id="+r+c+"></td></tr>";
                }

            }
        }
    }
    $("#rooms").html(innerHtml);
```

but here the values of r and c are not getting increament,can any one tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Define for each row

```
    var tr = table.insertRow(0);
```

For the number of cells try to use

```
    var td = tr.insertCell(0);
```

and to set `id` to `td` try to use

```
td.id= currentListItem.get_item('Room');
```

And to set value of cell

```
td.innerHTML= "your value";
```

Regarding your situation it's prefered to create a function to create your rows and cells based on your requirment as paramter and **call it in while**.

**Example**

Give your main table ID as `myTable`

[image]

```
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);


for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    var cell = row.insertCell(i);
    cell.id = i;
    cell.innerHTML = "Qassas" + i;
    }
}
```

**OutPut**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `while (enumerator.moveNext())` statement will iterate through all items before letting the indexes (c & r) to increment.

If you want one item per cell, try replacing 'while' with 'if'.

ps. not really a SharePoint question is it? :-)

Comment: no change in result after changing while to if

Comment: i posted this as  because i thought am using list and all that if somebdy replied then there should not be any need of explaination regarding things user